# Haskell: getProcessStatus blocking SIGINT

Tags: haskell, process, signals, posix

I'm trying to write a simple shell in Haskell, but I cant get the signal handling to work. If no command is running, sending `SIGINT` to the shell process triggers the signal handler. But when a blocking call to `getProcessStatus` is made, the signal is ignored. Sending a signal immediately to the child process of course kills the child and makes the blocking call return.

Replacing the blocking call with `Control.Concurrent.threadDelay` does not prevent the signal, i.e., everything works as intended. Replacing the blocking flag to `getProcessStatus` with `False` makes the function return before the child process has finished.

Reference to process package: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.1.0/docs/System-Posix-Process.html#v:getProcessStatus

The relevant code is below, see the (only) commented line.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    pidRef <- (newIORef [] :: IO (IORef [ProcessID]))
    setSigHant pidRef
    doPrompt pidRef

printPrompt :: IO ()
printPrompt = fdWrite stdError "λ➔ " >> return ()

doPrompt :: IORef [ProcessID] -> IO ()
doPrompt pidRef = do
    printPrompt
    tryLine <- try getLine :: IO (Either SomeException String)
    case tryLine of 
        Left _ -> do
            putStrLn ""
            exitSuccess
        Right line -> do
            tryCl <- try (parse line) :: IO (Either SomeException [Command])
            case tryCl of 
                Left e -> fdWrite stdError (show e ++ "\n") >> return ()
                Right cl -> 
                    if length cl > 0 && (cmd . head) cl == "cd" then
                        cd (head cl)
                    else do
                        execCommands pidRef cl (stdInput, stdOutput)
                        pids <- readIORef pidRef

                        -- This call to getProcessStatus blocks the signals
                        _ <- sequence $ map (getProcessStatus True False) pids
                        _ <- writeIORef pidRef []
                        return ()
            doPrompt pidRef

setSigHant :: (IORef [ProcessID]) -> IO ()
setSigHant pidRef = do
    let handler = Catch (sigIntHandler pidRef)
    installHandler sigINT handler Nothing
    return ()


sigIntHandler :: (IORef [ProcessID]) -> IO ()
sigIntHandler pidRef = do
    pids <- readIORef pidRef
    sequence_ $ map (signalProcess sigINT) pids
    fdWrite stdError "\n"
    printPrompt
```

Comment: Are you working on Linux or in Windows (Cygwin) ?

Comment: Also, does compiling with -threaded chage anything?

Comment: Linux (Debian). `-threaded` did the trick, thanks! I'm new to posting at SO, do I accept an answer or something?

Comment: I have expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getProcessStatus` uses an [interruptible FFI](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/ffi.html#ffi-interruptible) call internally. But why is `-threaded` necessary?

[This blog post](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com.es/2015/05/handling-control-c-in-haskell.html) about handling ctrl-c in Haskell suggests that signal handling is done in a separate thread that kills the main thread using an asynchronous exception:

> When the user hits Ctrl-C, GHC raises an async exception of type
>   UserInterrupt on the main thread. This happens because GHC installs an
>   interrupt handler which raises that exception, sending it to the main
>   thread with throwTo.

But the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.4.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#g:5) for the async package mentions that:

> Different Haskell implementations have different characteristics with
>   regard to which operations block all threads.
>
> Using GHC without the -threaded option, **all foreign calls will block
>   all other Haskell threads in the system**, although I/O operations will
>   not. With the -threaded option, only foreign calls with the unsafe
>   attribute will block all other threads.

So maybe that's why proper handling of SIGINT in presence of interruptible ffi calls requires `-threaded`: otherwise, the thread that throws the asynchronous exception will be prevented from running.